# How to create a SKSpriteNode with Custom GKComponent?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, gameplay-kit

So im currently working on a game with `spriteKit` and `gameplayKit`. I've created a custom `GKComponent` class that I'm giving to certain `SKSpriteNode` via the scene inspector in Xcode (image). Now, when I want to re-create random `SKSpritenodes` with the same `GKComponent`, it doesn't seems to work because the overridden update method of my custom `GKComponent` is not working. Any clues?

[image]

I've tried to give the node a new entity object (since it was returning nil) and I gave that entity my custom `GKComponent` but nothing is working

```
// In scene                
let node = SKSpriteNode(texture: "coin", color: UIColor.clear, size: CGSize(width: 60, height: 60))
let entities: GKEntity! = GKEntity()
let component: CollectableComponent = CollectableComponent()
component.itemType = 1

node.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
node.zPosition = 6
node.setScale(0.5)
node.size = CGSize(width: 60, height: 60)
node.position = CGPoint(x: 90, y: 90)
entities.addComponent(component)
node.entity = entities
self.scene?.addChild(node)


// GKComponent

class CustomComponent: GKComponent {
    var node: SKSpriteNode?

    @GKInspectable var itemType: Int = 0
    @GKInspectable var isStatic: Bool = false

    override init() {
        super.init()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override func update(deltaTime seconds: TimeInterval) {
        if node == nil {
            if let nodeComponent = self.entity?.component(ofType: GKSKNodeComponent.self){
                node = nodeComponent.node as? SKSpriteNode
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Desired behaviour: if the `nodeComponent` variable in `CustomComponent` is not nil, I would like to make it run an animation like this:

`node = nodeComponent.node as? SKSpriteNode; node.run(SKAction.moveBy(x: 0, y: 15, duration: 0.3));`

but with the code, the action would not be running

Comment: What do yuo mean by "but nothing is working". What is the expected behavious?

Comment: Well let say that normally if the nodeComponent variable in CustomComponent is not nil, I would like to make it run an animation like this: node = nodeComponent.node as? SKSpriteNode; node.run(SKAction.moveBy(x: 0, y: 15, duration: 0.3)); // With the code, the action would not be running

Comment: Nothing is mapped..... You create a component, and you create a node, but at no point do you ever link the two together (You probably just want to create a copy of the node on the scene instead of creating new instances of things)

Comment: I created a node, a gkentity and a component instance since the node has no entity that can receive my component. I then add the component to the entity I created and after that give that entity to my node. This is how they are all linked together. The custom component is here even when I print the attributes of my node but yet the init() method is called but not the update one

Comment: `node.entity` is a weak reference, so it is vanishing on you once you leave set up.  No map ever happens

Comment: btw, using update to set your node is a terrible idea.  You do not want to constantly be doing that check.  Make node a lazy variable, and the first time you go to access it, it will grab the node from the GKSKNodeComponent.  Also, `GKSKNodeComponent` is not given to you for free either unless you are using the builder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the way you want to be doing this.

Take note that you need to retain your entities, so a global variable is needed.

Also, when you add a node to `GKSKNodeComponent`, the `node.entity` variable is set automatically.

```
class GameScene : SKScene{
    var entities: [GKEntity] = [GKEntity]()

    func doSomething(){


        let node = SKSpriteNode(texture: "coin", color: UIColor.clear, size: CGSize(width: 60, height: 60))
        node.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
node.zPosition = 6
        node.setScale(0.5) //<--- YUCK!!!!!
        node.size = CGSize(width: 60, height: 60)
        node.position = CGPoint(x: 90, y: 90)
        self.scene?.addChild(node)

        let entity = GKEntity()
        let nodeComponent : GKSKNodeComponent = GKSKNodeComponent(node:node)
        let component: CollectableComponent = CollectableComponent()
        component.itemType = 1
        entity.addComponent(nodeComponent)
        entity.addComponent(component)
        entities.append(entity)

    }
}

// GKComponent

class CustomComponent: GKComponent {
    //We want this line to crash if node is empty, so do not use ?
    lazy var node: SKSpriteNode! = {return self.entity!.component(ofType: GKSKNodeComponent.self).node as? SKSpriteNode! }

    @GKInspectable var itemType: Int = 0
    @GKInspectable var isStatic: Bool = false

    override init() {
        super.init()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override func update(deltaTime seconds: TimeInterval) {

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I just started using the components so there was things that I wasn't aware of. You solved my issue, im really thankful! Thanks for the advices